# Android change layout and set onclick event on button in new layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have application with two layouts (main and detail). Application starts with main layout. I have button on main layout. When i click on it i call `setContentView(R.layout.detail);`.

Now i have set new layout with button and i need set onclick event on this new layout button.

I tried set both events in `onCreate()` method. After that works only first button on main layout. Button on detail layout don't works.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the layout of your activity? Why can't you use two activities instead: Main and Detail?

Comment: try to define your main and detail view in one layout and try to hide/show on appropriate button click.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a recommended way to change the layouts.
Anyways, once you change the layout by setContentView(R.layout.detail) , you need to set the onclickListener of the button again.
After setting the new view, try to findviewbyid(urbuttonid) and setonclicklistener for this.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This question has very simple solution:

When you set another content view , Initialize again button of new layout like this:

`Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  b1.setOnClickListener(this);`

after that your click event goes for second view's button...

or

you can do assign different id's and names to both buttons that you can handle each button click by its id.

or

you can assign click listener for each button on the views.

Good Luck